# How to print only the line which contains a blank lines before and after

Tags: awk, sed

How i can print only the line which contains blank `line(s)` before and after it.
I'm trying various awk and grep combination but somehow unable to get it.

```
tuv0657


tuv2330


tuv2133              Unable to get the ssh connection


tuv1988              Unable to get the ssh connection


tuv1049


tuv1683              Unable to get the ssh connection


tuv2101
```

**Desired:**

```
tuv0657
tuv1049
tuv2330
tuv2101
```

**What i tried:**

i tried below but did not get the results..

```
$ awk  '{if ($2=="") print $0}' file
$ grep -E --line-number --with-filename '^$'
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Its OP who has tagged `awk`, `sed` in question, they should be present in question IMHO, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thanks for commenting, i have update the Post, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Very Good for adding your efforts, please keep it up and do always add them in your question to avoid close votes on your question, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thanks for the great help, i will be checking and accepting the relevant if that works for me.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You can get the output you want from the sample input you provided with `awk 'NF==1'` but it's not clear if that satisfies what you mean by "print only the line which contains blank line(s) before and after it" (it's not clear how your expected output represents that condition either though).

Comment: All the non-blank lines have blank lines before and after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk -v RS="" 'NF==1' Input_file
tuv0657
tuv2330
tuv1049
tuv2101
```

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 , can you please write an explanation that will be helpful for me and posterity .

Comment: @user294110, sure, shortest explanation will be: Setting RS to paragraph mode and then checking if field is only 1 then print that line simply :) will add it in my answer in my few mins or so, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example data, try the following awk solution:

```
awk '$1 !="" && $2 == "" { print }' file
```

Where the first space separated field is not blank and the second field is blank, print the line.

Comment: How does this get the order the OP wanted?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/^\S+$/p' file
```

Print the current line if it only contains the first field.